# Anypoint Platform : How to publish OPEN API components in Anypoint Exchange?

Tags: mule, openapi, raml, anypoint-platform

Scenario : There are say two API specifications , API_Spec_1 and API_Spec_2 and they both share some schemas, say schema_1 and schema_2.
While designing, I want to **publish schema_1 and schema_2** to anypoint exchange, so that I can reuse them through **$ref** in the main API Specifcations API_Spec_1 and API_Spec_2.

How can I achieve this?

Note:
In case of RAML we define raml fragments and publish them to Anypoint Exchange. I am looking for the alternative of this approach in Open API specification design in Anypoint platform.

Comment: [`components` section](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/components/) and [`$ref`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/)?

Comment: My question is if 2 or more specifications share the same components, how can I define all the components in one file and then externalise it. Then in each API specification, i can import and ref only those components which are required.